# Scroll top after showing a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have Bootstrap tabs on my page, but when I click on it, the tabs are hidden. Is there a way to scroll the position up so the tabs can be seen? Nothing I have found helped me. I can't change positions of the tabs or use hidden anchors - the tabs are the anchor.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active bio" role="presentation"><a href="#bio" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">biografie</a></li>
    <li class="films hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" role="presentation"><a href="#films" aria-controls="films" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">filmografie</a></li>
    <li class="trivia hidden-xs" role="presentation"><a href="#trivia" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">zajímavosti</a></li>
    <li class="awards hidden-xs" role="presentation"><a href="#awards" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ocenění</a></li>
    <li class="videos hidden-xs" role="presentation"><a href="#videos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">videa</a></li>
    <li class="gallery hidden-xs" role="presentation"><a href="#gallery" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">galerie</a></li>
    <li class="contact hidden-xs" role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the JS I use to get to the anchors:

```
  $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
  });

  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
```

Page with tabs: http://testovani-frameworku.wz.cz/jennifer-lawrence.html#awards

Comment: Just a tip: `location.hash` is a thing, and includes the `#` and everything after it.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the very top, you could do it a couple ways

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

or

```
$("mySelector").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
```

or

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
```

It just depends what type of effect you want. Could just set the scrollTop to 0 (which is very top) if you don't want animation effect. Could just use the vanilla JS `window.scrollTo(x,y)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work anywhere I put it. I really don't know what more to do.

Comment: Where are you placing it at when you try? Also, is any of this inside of a wrapper/container DIV? If you provide some of the surrounding code, I can be more specific for ya.

Comment: I wanted to try it when clicking on a tab so: 

$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });

Comment: My pages are very comprehensive and I use Bootstrap.

Comment: Without seeing it in action, it's hard for me to say, but it sounds like it's losing the position after it's being displayed. Have you tried to place it after the tabs `.tab('show')`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it everywhere. I'm gonna upload the page somewhere.

Comment: The `#awards` at the end of your URL is what is causing your problem. The `#awards` DIV is below your tabs, it's taking it to the top of that DIV, which doesn't include the TABS. You can fix that by either wrapping the DIVs and have it #divWrapper in your URL, or simply removing that. Considering what you're doing, you'll want to have the tabs contained inside of the DIV so it doesn't do it everytime you click another tab.

Comment: Oh, I've overlooked this... thank you. But I will still maybe need to scroll up.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Hope it goes smooth for ya!

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I've solved it. I've added "-tab" at the end of a tab's ID and the original ID has the link.

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    id = id.substring(0, id.length-4);
    window.location.hash = id;    
});

var hash = (window.location.hash);
$('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '-tab"]').tab('show');
```